# C Rock paper scissors game: what did I do wrong?

Tags: c

sorry if this seems like a dumb question and if the code is hard to read but I've started learning C 2 days ago to prepare for 42's piscine and I'm a complete beginner.

For the first time I wrote a program that compiled without any errors, I was so proud...

Turns out it doesn't work at all and I have no idea why.
No matter how many times I input my choice (r, p or s), it keeps asking me again.

Can someone explain to me what's going on?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    // Declaring integers
    int player_score = 0, computer_score = 0;

    // Declaring char
    char player_choice2;

    // Welcome message and rules
    printf(
        "\nWELCOME TO ROCK PAPER SCISSORS !\n\nFirst to get three points "
        "wins\n\n");

    // Setting a seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Starting new game loop
    for (;;) {
        // Starting game loop
        do {
            // Declaring char
            char player_choice;

            // Computer's choice
            int computer_choice = rand() % 3;

            // Displaying scores
            if (player_score != 0 && computer_score != 0) {
                printf("Your score: %d\nComputer's score: %d\n\n", player_score,
                       computer_score);
            }

            // Prompting the player to make it's choice and scanning it
            printf(
                "Choose between r for rock, p for paper and s for "
                "scissors\n\n");
            scanf(" %c", &player_choice);

            // Determining if player or computer loses
            if (player_choice == 'r' && computer_choice == '0') {
                printf("Rock! It's a tie.\n\n");
            } else if (player_choice == 'p' && computer_choice == '0') {
                printf("Rock!\n\n");
                player_score += 1;
            } else if (player_choice == 's' && computer_choice == '0') {
                printf("Rock!\n\n");
                computer_score += 1;
            } else if (player_choice == 'r' && computer_choice == '1') {
                printf("Paper!\n\n");
                computer_score += 1;
            } else if (player_choice == 'p' && computer_choice == '1') {
                printf("Paper! It's a tie.\n\n");
            } else if (player_choice == 's' && computer_choice == '1') {
                printf("Paper!\n\n");
                player_score += 1;
            } else if (player_choice == 'r' && computer_choice == '2') {
                printf("Scissors!\n\n");
                player_score += 1;
            } else if (player_choice == 'p' && computer_choice == '2') {
                printf("Scissors!\n\n");
                computer_score += 1;
            } else if (player_choice == 's' && computer_choice == '2') {
                printf("Scissors! It's a tie.\n\n");
            }

        } while (player_score < 3 && computer_score < 3);

        if (player_score == 3) {
            printf("Congratulations, you won !\n\n");
        } else {
            printf("Sorry, you lost !\n\n");
        }

        printf("Do you wish to play again ? Enter Y for yes or N for no\n");
        scanf(" %c", &player_choice2);
        if (player_choice2 == 'N') {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `computer_choice` is an integer value of `0`, `1`, or `2`. The constants `'0'`, `'1'` and `'2'`, while `int`s, will almost certainly not have the same integer value (in ASCII they have the decimal integer values `48`, `49`, and `50`, respectively). Try `computer_choice == 0`, and so on.

Comment: Note that something like `const char *RPS = "rps"; char computer_choice = RPS[rand() % strlen(RPS)];` will get you the computer's selection as a character (`'r'`, `'p'`, or `'s'`), similar to the user's input, which might help you to better reason about the structure of your comparisons.

Comment: Some suggestions: homogenise the three play options for each player. Use a 2D lookup table to find the winner. Use an array of strings to prompt and report meaningful game token names.

Comment: Another suggestion: build your program in smaller steps than you did. Instead of writing code to play three games and the logic to repeat for another game, write code for *one* game. When that works properly, then you can add more complexity. That also suggests a single game should be in another function. Don't cram everything into `main()`.

Comment: You could have detected the problem (or at least got a clue) by having a final `else {printf("None of the above");}` MISRA mandates a final else, probably for reasons like this.

Answer (score 2):

In your if statements you have treated the computers choice(int) as a char by by wrapping the numbers in ' ' the corrected if statements:

```
// Determining if player or computer loses
    if (player_choice == 'r' && computer_choice == 0) {
        printf("Rock! It's a tie.\n\n");
    } else if (player_choice == 'p' && computer_choice == 0) {
        printf("Rock!\n\n");
        player_score += 1;
    } else if (player_choice == 's' && computer_choice == 0) {
        printf("Rock!\n\n");
        computer_score += 1;
    } else if (player_choice == 'r' && computer_choice == 1) {
        printf("Paper!\n\n");
        computer_score += 1;
    } else if (player_choice == 'p' && computer_choice == 1) {
        printf("Paper! It's a tie.\n\n");
    } else if (player_choice == 's' && computer_choice == 1) {
        printf("Paper!\n\n");
        player_score += 1;
    } else if (player_choice == 'r' && computer_choice == 2) {
        printf("Scissors!\n\n");
        player_score += 1;
    } else if (player_choice == 'p' && computer_choice == 2) {
        printf("Scissors!\n\n");
        computer_score += 1;
    } else if (player_choice == 's' && computer_choice == 2) {
        printf("Scissors! It's a tie.\n\n");
    }
```

you can also replace "+= 1" with ++ like so:

```
// Determining if player or computer loses
    if (player_choice == 'r' && computer_choice == 0) {
        printf("Rock! It's a tie.\n\n");
    } else if (player_choice == 'p' && computer_choice == 0) {
        printf("Rock!\n\n");
        player_score++;
    } else if (player_choice == 's' && computer_choice == 0) {
        printf("Rock!\n\n");
        computer_score++;
    } else if (player_choice == 'r' && computer_choice == 1) {
        printf("Paper!\n\n");
        computer_score++;
    } else if (player_choice == 'p' && computer_choice == 1) {
        printf("Paper! It's a tie.\n\n");
    } else if (player_choice == 's' && computer_choice == 1) {
        printf("Paper!\n\n");
        player_score++;
    } else if (player_choice == 'r' && computer_choice == 2) {
        printf("Scissors!\n\n");
        player_score++;
    } else if (player_choice == 'p' && computer_choice == 2) {
        printf("Scissors!\n\n");
        computer_score++;
    } else if (player_choice == 's' && computer_choice == 2) {
        printf("Scissors! It's a tie.\n\n");
    }
```

Also your question is not "dumb"